# Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception. Converter is defined before it is referenced

Tags: wpf

I know this looks like a duplicate question but I've tried the solution proposed in similar questions that have been asked.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <common:BooleanToVisibilityMultipleConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityMultiConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Margin="5">

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 <Button Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="2" 
            Margin="5"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"                
            Background="{x:Static sds:AppBrushes.Green}" 
            MinWidth="{StaticResource SdsButtonMinWidth}" 
            Content="{x:Static res:Resources.UpdatePlantNameButton}" 
            Command="{Binding CreateDatabaseCommand}">
       <Button.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoolToVisibilityMultiConverter}">
                <Binding Path="IsDatabaseCreated"/>
                <Binding Path="IsHistory"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.Visibility>
    </Button>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My converter code -

```
namespace ABB.SDS.Batch.Common
{
   public class BooleanToVisibilityMultipleConverter : IMultiValueConverter
   {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.OfType<bool>().All(b => b) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

I am referring the converter only in one place and that is after the converter has been defined. I still get this exception
       "The method or operation is not implemented.
Resulting in: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '111' and line position '18'"

What am I missing? Are there any other use cases in which this exception is thrown?

Comment: Can you paste your converter code here. It looks like you did not impement comething in converter. Does your converter implement IMultiValueConverter interface?

Comment: Added the converter code

Comment: "It looks like you did not impement something in converter". Not at all. The exception has nothing to do with the converter implementation. From what you've shown here, your XAML should just work. Did you try to rebuild all or restart Visual Studio?

Comment: Show the stack trace of the exception please. (Including inner exceptions)

Comment: What about `SdsButtonMinWidth` resource? I don't see its definition in your XAML. Is it defined before it is used?